# Definir dimensión de un array en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy intentando programar álgebra de tensores, efiniendo una variable "tensor" como esta:

```
typedef struct TENSOR
{
    float(*) elemento; //elementos del tensor

    unsigned int co_indices;

    unsigned int contra_indices;

    unsigned int N;

} tensor;
```

La idea es que la variable `elemento` tuviera tantos subíndices como `co_indices + contra_indices` ¿hay alguna forma de definir la *dimensión* de `elemento` en tiempo de ejecución?

Edito (creo que no he formulado mi pregunta con exactitud, y cambio el título como se sugiere en los comentarios):
Mi pregunta no es tanto asignar memoria al array "elemento" (usando malloc), si no definir en tiempo de ejecución la dimensión de este array. Es decir por ejemplo, si (co_indice + contra_indice = 3) la asignación de memoria para "elemento" sería algo así:

```
 elemento = (float***)malloc(sizeof(float**) * N);

 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    elemento[i]=(float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * N);

 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
       elemento[i][j]=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
 }
```

¿Se puede hacer este proceso de forma general (para dimensión cualquiera) y en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: No es posible definir un struct con tamaño variable (asi como no es posible definir una clase de tamaño variable). El compilador debe saber exactamente cuanto espacio reservar cuando de declara cada variable. Una vez dicho esto, ¿qué es lo que necesitas hacer y en qué lenguaje? En C++ puedes utilizar las ventajas de las estructuras estándar (como vectores y listas). En C tienes que reservar y liberar el espacio tu mismo dentro de la ejecución.

Comment: Otro comentario: el propósito de las preguntas en stack overflow no es que resuelvan tu duda, sino que se genere conocimiento que otros puedan usar. En ese sentido, un mejor título para tu pregunta es "cómo definir un struct de tamaño variable" (o algo más adecuado a la necesidad que tengas).

Answer (score 1):

> ¿hay alguna forma de definir la "dimensión" de "elemento" en tiempo de ejecución?

Tienes que usar memoria dinámica... y aquí ya tienes dos caminos posibles:

### Usar malloc y realloc

`malloc` sirve para solicitar memoria dinámica al sistema, mientras que `realloc` sirve para modificar la cantidad de memoria reservada (los datos almacenados en la memoria se mantienen).

Con esto en mente puedes usar `malloc` para la reserva inicial y `realloc` cada vez que necesites añadir nuevos elementos:

```
tensor t;
t.elemento = (float*)malloc((t.co_indices+t.contra_indices)* sizeof(float));

// ...
t.co_indices++;
float* ptr = (float*)realloc(t.elemento,(t.co_indices+t.contra_indices)* sizeof(float));
if( ptr )
  t.elemento = ptr;
else
  /* error al reservar la memoria */
```

### usar solo realloc

`realloc` también puede usarse para hacer la reserva inicial de memoria, pero para ello es necesario que el puntero que se le pase sea `NULL`... así que hay que tener cuidado al inicializar la estructura:

```
tensor NuevoTensor()
{
  tensor t;
  t.elemento = 0;
  t.co_indices = 0;
  t.contra_indices = 0;
  t.N = 0;

  return t;
};

int GestionarReserva(tensor *t)
{
  float* ptr = (float*)realloc(t->elemento,(t->co_indices+t->contra_indices)* sizeof(float));
  if( ptr )
  {
    t->elemento = ptr;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

tensor t = NuevoTensor();
t.co_indices = 1;
GestionarReserva(&t); // Se reserva memoria para 1 elemento

t.contra_indices = 10;
GestionarReserva(&t); // La reserva se amplia a 11 elementos
```